# Using single channel texture (OpenGL 2)?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

**Short storry:**

when I render anything using texture loaded like this

```
glTexImage2D   ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, width,  height, 0, GL_RED,   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels );
```

I get only black

---

**Long storry:**

I can get RGBA texture with alpha channel (e.g. text with transparent backgorund using this code):

**This code works:**

```
// === load
#define GL_ABGR 0x8000
SDL_Surface * surf = SDL_LoadBMP( "common_resources/dejvu_sans_mono_RGBA.bmp" );
glGenTextures  ( 1, &itex );
glBindTexture  ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, itex );
glTexImage2D   ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, surf->w,  surf->h, 0, GL_ABGR,   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surf->pixels );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
// ....
// === render
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, itex );
glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
drawString ( caption,             xmin, ymin+12, 6 );
```

renders like [image]

But I'm trying to use just one channel (8-bit; grayscale) images / textures instead of RGBA. These I cannot get to render neither with nor without transparancy. Whatever I do I get only black image.

**This doesn't**

```
// === load
#define GL_ABGR 0x8000
SDL_Surface * surf = SDL_LoadBMP( "common_resources/dejvu_sans_mono_Alpha.bmp" );
glGenTextures  ( 1, &itex );
glBindTexture  ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, itex );
glTexImage2D   ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, surf->w,  surf->h, 0, GL_RED,   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surf->pixels );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
// ....
// === render
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, itex );
glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
//glEnable(GL_BLEND);
//glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
//glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
drawString ( caption,             xmin, ymin+12, 6 );
```

renders like [image]

Notes:

1. I know that I should somehow use `glTexEnv` according to e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559394/opengl-es-how-to-tint-texture-with-color) but my main problem is that apparently the **monochrome texture does not render at all**
2. I tried also other `GL_LUMINANCE` and `GL_INTENSITY` instead of `GL_RED` in `glTexImage2D` with no difference
3. there are other questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184370/read-and-write-integer-1-channel-texture-opengl) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848901/opengl-use-single-channel-texture-as-alpha-channel-to-display-text) but mostly with OpenGL>3.0 and fragment shaders

Also, is it possible that my graphics card or driver does not support this ? I'm on ubuntu 16.04

```
GL_VENDOR:     Intel Open Source Technology Center
GL_RENDERER:   Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2) 
GL_VERSION:    3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
```

---

**for completeness** - although it is not importaint the `drawString` looks like this:

```
drawString ( caption,             xmin, ymin+12, 6 ){
  const int nchars = 95;
  float persprite = 1.0f/nchars;
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  for(int i=0; i<65536; i++){
    if( str[i] == 0 ) break; // 0-terminated string
    int isprite = str[i] - 33; // 33 is offset of meaningfull ASCII characters
    float offset  = isprite*persprite+(persprite*0.57);
    float xi = i*sz + x;
    glTexCoord2f( offset          , 1.0f ); glVertex3f( xi,    y,    3.0f );
    glTexCoord2f( offset+persprite, 1.0f ); glVertex3f( xi+sz, y,    3.0f );
    glTexCoord2f( offset+persprite, 0.0f ); glVertex3f( xi+sz, y+sz*2, 3.0f );
    glTexCoord2f( offset          , 0.0f ); glVertex3f( xi,    y+sz*2, 3.0f );
  }
  glEnd();
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I want to try to help you. In my projects I am using this arguments for generating textures from grayscale source images:

```cpp
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 1, width, height, 0, GL_RED,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

As written in [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml), third argument - number of color components (1 in our case). Need to check integer value of `GL_R8` or replace it explicitly.

`GL_RED` means that you place luminances in red channel (not in each red, green, blue channels as for grayscale image).

Comment: thanks, I tried `glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 1,       surf->w,  surf->h, 0, GL_RED,       GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surf->pixels );` but the resut is still the same ... maybe really intel GPU does not support it (?)

Comment: @ProkopHapala , are you have command ```glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);``` ? I am usally calls ```glBindTexture```->```glPixelStorei```->```x2 glTexParameteri```->```glTexImage2D```

Comment: You should never use bare numbers for the internal format of a texture. Always used sized image formats, even for greyscale images.

Comment: now I tried to add `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` but did not helped

Comment: @ProkopHapala , I think that resulting texture in memory has zeros at alpha channel (we are loading our intensities to red).

Comment: @ProkopHapala, Hello again! Please try to use ```glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, width, height, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);```